# C# CRUD problem - The UPDATE panel does not work as I expect

Tags: c#, database, crud

I try to make a program that supports full CRUD, but... The update part does not work

```
   using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Text;

        namespace MyLibary.Models
        {
            class UpdateBooks
            {
                public void updateCompBook()
                {
                    using (var bookUp = new BookContext())
                    {
                        // This is a full CRUD program that saves books in a databases
                        // I have some problems with the Update part..
                        ShowFutureBooks bookShow = new ShowFutureBooks(); 
                        bookShow.FutureBooks(); // shows all three books

                        Console.WriteLine("Type the id of the book you want to update"); // currently there is 3 books saved in the database

                        int id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // lets say i that i choose the if 1

                        // what i would like to do and cannot, is that get only the book that has id 1 so that i can update it


                        Console.WriteLine("Update the book according to following: BookName, BookAuthor, BookSummary");



                        BooksToRead bU = new BooksToRead()
                        {
                            BookName = Console.ReadLine()
                          , BookAuthor = Console.ReadLine()
                          , BookSumary = Console.ReadLine()
                        }; 
                        bookUp.BooksToRead.Add(bU);
                        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to save changes.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        bookUp.SaveChanges();
                        Console.WriteLine("The bok has been updated!");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like to take a book id from the database and then update that specific book but it does not work.

Comment: Define "does not work".  What specifically fails?  How specifically does the failing operation behave and what specifically were you expecting?

Comment: When the program is started the user will see all the books which is currently three books. Then the user will type which book to be updated by the id of that specific book for example:    int id = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());, then i want to show that specific book that the user type in and update it. Hope I managed to define in a good way!

Comment: Saying what you want the program to do doesn't explain what it's currently doing that isn't working.  From the comments in your code it sounds like you're just asking how to get an element from a collection.  What have you tried?  Maybe something like: `bookUp.BooksToRead.Single(b => b.Id == id)` ?  Mostly a guess, since we don't know your model structure.  But the point is, where do you *try* to perform your operation and how does it fail?

Comment: Post SaveChanges event to see what you have done there

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
    BooksToRead bU = new BooksToRead()
    {
        BookName = Console.ReadLine()
        , BookAuthor = Console.ReadLine()
        , BookSumary = Console.ReadLine()
    }; 
    bookUp.BooksToRead.Add(bU);
```

creates a new BooksToRead object and then you add it in your list. This will actually perform an insert instead of an update. You have to loop through your list and find the BooksToRead object with the inserted id and then change its values prior to saving it.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update then you should first load the book you want to edit

```
var bookToEdit = bookUp.BooksToRead.Find( id );
```

Now modify the properties you like

```
bookToEdit.BookName = Console.ReadLine();
...
```

and when you are finished editing the save the changes with

```
bookUp.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I will try this one as well, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

When adding crud to your application i would recommend to put this in one class. This class will then end with the name `repository`(look it up you will find many examples).

```
public class BookRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method will update the entity by using the bookId.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bookId">The is of the book</param>
    /// <param name="name">The book Name (to be updated)</param>
    /// <param name="author">The book author (to be updated)</param>
    /// <param name="summary">The book summary (to be updated)</param>
    public void Update(int bookId, string name, string author, string summary)
    {
        var _context = new BookContext();
        var myBook = _context.Books.First(book => g.bookId == bookId);//finds the first entity with the given bookId
        myBook.name = name;//this for all variables
        _context.SaveChanges();//save the changes to the database.
    }
}
```

Calling the methode will look something like: `new BookRepository.Update(0, "", "", "");`.

Please do note that the above is a simple example. There will be needed some changes to make it work with your specific data model. 
See the [following link](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/repository-design-pattern-csharp/) to know more about the repository pattern.

Comment: This is really simple example. Any practical application with more than one user needs to deal with concurrency and consequently with lifetime of DataContext. Do not try to write methods this way.